# Scraping Data in URL format via Android / jsoup

Tags: java, android, url, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm attempting to scrape a URL from a HTML table however every time I do so I get the HREF title data instead of the URL - does anyone how this can be resolved/avoided?

```
<table class="datagrid">
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>Location</th>
        </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><a href="redirector.cfm?ID=93bd5121-7a3b-4a56-a576-f432e542047a&page=1&&amp;lname=&amp;fname=" title="501207593">501207593&nbsp;</a></td>
                <td>AARON, JUSTIN COLBY&nbsp;</td>
                <td>M&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Facility 1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><a href="redirector.cfm?ID=c5629a92-7113-487c-ba9b-1e62203ab08d&page=1&&amp;lname=&amp;fname=" title="501302750">501302750&nbsp;</a></td>
                <td>AARONSON, CARY HOWARD&nbsp;</td>
                <td>M&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Facility 2</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><a href="redirector.cfm?ID=66d01768-5686-44eb-ac6a-16eb783f52d0&page=1&&amp;lname=&amp;fname=" title="501306284">501306284&nbsp;</a></td>
                <td>ABBOTT, LAUREA &nbsp;</td>
                <td>F&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Facility 3</td>
            </tr>
```

SOURCE:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    String url = "http://google.com";
    String tr;
    Document doc;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        new MyTask().execute(url);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog prog;

        String title = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            prog.setMessage("Loading....");
            prog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                Element tableElement = doc.select(".datagrid").first();

                Elements tableRows = tableElement.select("tr");
                for (Element row : tableRows) {
                    Elements cells = row.select("td");
                    if (cells.size() > 0) {
                        title = cells.get(0).text() + "; "
                                + cells.get(1).text() + "; "
                                + cells.get(2).text() + "; "
                                + cells.get(3).text();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return title;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String title) {
            super.onPostExecute(title);
            prog.dismiss();
            tv.setText(title);
        }
    }
}
```

CURRENT RESULTS:

501306284; ABBOTT, LAUREA; F ; Facility 3

DESIRED RESULTS:

redirector.cfm?ID=66d01768-5686-44eb-ac6a-16eb783f52d0&page=1&&lname=&fname=" title="501306284; ABBOTT, LAUREA; F ; Facility 3

or better yet...

DESIRED RESULTS

Click HERE for more info (<-URL);  ABBOTT, LAUREA; F ; Facility 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be getting just the [text](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text%28%29):

```
cells.get(0).text()
```

I think this is what you are trying to do

```
cells.get(0).child(0).attr("href")
```

Check the docs in this [link](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#attr%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I tried the following but it doesn't seem to be working...
  title = cells.get(0).attr("href") + " ; "
                            +cells.get(0).text() + "; "
                                + cells.get(1).text() + "; "
                                + cells.get(2).text() + "; "
                                + cells.get(3).text();

Comment: Oh, because you were iterating over the `TD`. And then you have to ask for the first child of the `TD`. The updated answer should work.